# Github Workflow Maven Caching - Multi-Module Project

Tags: maven, github, caching, github-actions

I am working on integrating Sonar for a multi-module Maven Project which has 3 modules. I need to speed up the Maven Build Process by enabling caching. Sonar Reports are working correctly but still the caching is not happening. Below here find the Github Workflow File with the configurations which I want to cache the dependencies only relevant to the **cloud-pci-ui** module

[Module Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XEOJk.png)

[Maven Caching Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4BUTv.png)

```
name: Analyze pull request
on:
  # Trigger analysis when open edit, synchronize or re-opene a pull request. 
  pull_request:
    types: [opened, edited, synchronize, reopened]
env:
  # Sets environment variable
  AWS_REGION : us-east-1

jobs:
  buildAndAnalysePR:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
        with:
          # Disabling shallow clone is recommended for improving relevancy of reporting
          fetch-depth: 0
      - uses: actions/setup-java@v2
        with:
          distribution: 'adopt'
          java-version: '8'
          cache: 'maven'
      - name: Cache local Maven repository
        uses: actions/cache@v2
        with:
          path: ~/cloud-pci-ui/.m2/repository/
          key: ${{ runner.os }}-maven-${{ hashFiles('**/pom.xml') }}
      - name: Build PCI-API
        run: |
          cd cloud-pci-api
          mvn clean install -DskipTests
```